# LyX -- IEEE Transactions -- Can't See Authors and Affiliations

Tags: tex, pdflatex, lyx, ieee

I downloaded and am using the IEEE Transactions template -- I just imported the raw conference .tex from the zip file.  When I use the View pdf (pdflatex), none of the author or affiliation information appears.  Just the title and then, in two-column format, the Abstract, the Introduction, and other sections that come with the template.

I am relatively new to `LyX` \ `TeX`.  I am using `Version 2.1.3`.

Edit1: *** It appears that if `\maketitle` comes before `\author{...}` that the author information will not be printed to the .pdf.

Answer (score 1):

LyX already has an IEEE Transactions template.

In LyX just go to File > New from Template and select "IEEEtran-TransMag.lyx".

The title and author names show up for me.